# Proof writing for the basis of the vector space of polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials in $x$ of degree $\le n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that the set  $\{1,x,x^2......,x^n\}$ is a basis for $V$. Extend this basis so that it becomes a basis for the set of all polynomials in $x$.

I've attempted to write the proof but doubt if it's correct. If its correct, can I get some tips to make it look more academic.

**PROOF $\colon$ -**

$$S = \{1,x,x^2,......,x^n\}$$
Taking linear combinations from the set S, we get -
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...........+a_nx^n$$
Which is a polynomial of degree $n$
$$\implies span(1,x,x^2,.......,x^n) = V$$
Now, for some linear combination of S, assume -
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...........+a_nx^n = 0$$
Differentiating it succesively upto $n$ time, we get a system of homogenous linear equations for $a$ with coefficient matrix -
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&      x&      x^2& \cdots&  x^{n-1}& x^n\\  
0&      1&      2x& \cdots&  (n-1)x^{n-2}&            nx^{n-1}\\  
0&      0&      2& \cdots&  (n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}&    n(n-1)x^{n-2}\\  
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\\  
0&       0&      0&        \cdots&        0&                            n!\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$det(A) = (1!)(2!).......(n!) \neq 0$$

$$\implies a_0 = a_1=..........=a_n= 0$$

Therefore, $\{1,x,x^2,.....x^n\}$ is linearly independent. Hence, the set $\{1,x,x^2,.....x^n\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Expanding the basis, such that it spans the vector space of $\mathbb{P}_{n+1}$, we get the set  -

$$Q = \{1,x,x^2,.......,x^n,x^{n+1}\}$$
Taking linear combinations such that -
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...........+a_nx^n+a_{n+1}x^{n+1} = 0$$
Assuming $a_{n+1} \neq 0$ -

$$\frac{a_0}{a_{n+1}}+\frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}}x+\frac{a_2}{a_{n+1}}x^2+...........+\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}x^n+x^{n+1} = 0$$
$$\implies x^{n+1} = -\frac{a_0}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}}x-\frac{a_2}{a_{n+1}}x^2-...........-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}x^n  $$
$$span(x^{n+1}) = span\left(-\frac{a_0}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}}x-\frac{a_2}{a_{n+1}}x^2-...........-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}x^n\right) = V$$

$$\implies span\left(1,x,x^2,.......,x^n,x^{n+1}\right) = V$$

This contradicts that $Q$ spans $\mathbb{P}_{n+1}$. This is because of our assumption, $a_{n+1} \neq 0$

$$\implies a_{n+1} = 0$$

Thus, $\{1,x,x^2,.......,x^n,x^{n+1}\}$ is linearly independent.
Therefore,$\{1,x,x^2,.......,x^n,x^{n+1}\}$ is a basis for the vector space under $\mathbb{P}_{n+1}$

Now, by using induction, we can show that $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4.......\}$ is a basis for the set of all polynomials in $x$

**END**

Comment: It is really obvious that the monomials $1,x, x^2, \ldots , x^n$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is almost right. I think it needs to be shown (even though it is trivial) that the set you've provided is independent, as you've only shown that any finite subset of it is independent. Likewise, you need to show that it spans all polynomials, as you've only shown that it spans every space of finite dimension.

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 And that is relevant because? Obvious doesn't mean not worth proving. It is a great exercise to get one's feet wet.

Comment: Your proof that $S$ is a basis for $\Bbb P_n$  applies to any $n.$  Change the name $S$ to $S_n$. Then $ Q=S_{n+1}$ is a basis for $\Bbb P_{n+1}$ by the same proof. So your 2nd part is redundant (but still logical). Your proof that $S$ is lin. indep is unusual but good.  The usual way: For polynomial $p$ with $k$ distinct zeroes  $x_1,...,x_k$  we have $p(x)=q(x)\prod_{j=1}^k(x-x_j)$ for all $x$,where $q$ is a polynomial with $deg(q)+k=deg(p)$. So if $deg(p)>0$ then $p$ has finitely many zeroes.

Comment: @DonThousand. A set $U$ is linearly independent iff every finite $V\subset U$ is lin. indep. from the def'n.  And $U$ spans a  vector-space $T$ iff $U$ spans every finite-dimensional vector-subspace of $T$, again from a def'n.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet As I said, it's a pretty easy proof. But, it is a nuance OP didn't address. I wouldn't say that at the level OP is at, these results are trivial from the definition.

Comment: @DonThousand . Well said..................